# Laravel vue data is not displayed in vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I wish to display data from my API request but it seems to be something wrong with something I can't figure out what it is... The data is not displaying on the page when I try to loop.
And I get the data from the API via the postman.
Please if anything is not explained correctly just write something...

This is my api.php
Route::get('/user', 'Api\UserController@index');

This is the Api\UserController:

```
public function index()
    {
        return UsersResource::collection(User::all());
    }
```

This is the vue script:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                users: [],
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.loadUsers();
        },
        methods: {
            loadUsers: function () {
                axios.get('api/user')
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.users= response.data.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is the table i'm trying to put the data in:

```
 <table >
          <tr>
          <th>
          <div class="form-text">
            TOP 10 USERS
          </div>
          </th>
          <th>RATING</th>
          <th>DEAL</th>
          <th>LINK</th>
          </tr>
          <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
          <td class="text-white">
              {{user.name}}
          </td>
          <td>/5</td>
          <td>% Discount</td>
          <td>
              <button class="btn buttonGlowGreen">VISIT</button>
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Please add console.log(response.data.data); before this.users= response.data.data; and tell me what you got in console?

Comment: I get the data perfectly

Comment: Open your vue console and in the components tab below the data, do you see users with that data?

Comment: No i don't see any data there.

Answer (score 1):

In your loadUser method, you are getting the response by `response` keyword then you must be set that for your users object in vue.

So replace the `this.users= users.data.data;` by `this.users= response.data.data;`

```
methods: {
    loadUsers() {
        axios.get('api/user')
            .then((response) => {
                this.users= response.data.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So sorry it was this.users= response.data.data; and it's my mistake . And it doesn't work even though .

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by removing

```
<script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

which was under my

```
<div id="app">.
```

From my blade page.
All working now!